# Forma de obter todos os resultados da consulta com SQL Command

Tags: sql-server

Estou tentando dar um select em duas colunas de uma table via sql command, executando uma procedure.

Codigo :

```
String consult = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

Procedure :

```
BEGIN
        SELECT Value, TimeStamp
        FROM AVL_Ignition
        WHERE TimeStamp = (SELECT MAX(TimeStamp) FROM AVL_Ignition)
        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
            select -1

END
```

Só estou obtendo o resultado do Value pois ele é o primeiro afetado. Existe alguma forma de obter todos os elementos resultados da consulta ? Já dei uma olhada nos métodos da classe sql command mas não achei nada promissor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `ExecuteScalar` pega somente a primeira coluna da primeira linha.

Para listar os registros, use o `ExecuteReader()`.

Por exemplo:

```
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    string valor = reader["Value"].ToString();
    DateTime data = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["TimeStamp"]);

    // fazer o que quiser com os valores
}
```